# patchValue to material datepicker not setting date

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a Firestore timestamp that I would like to assign to a material datepicker, but I am getting a date format error.

I've used datepipe to transform the firestore timestamp to 'yyyy-MM-dd' as inidicated by the below error.

The specified value "3/2/1981" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

The code that throws this is:

```
const bDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.user.birthday.toDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      console.log(bDate);
      this.form.patchValue( {
        birthday: bDate,
        firstName: this.user.firstName,
        lastName: this.user.lastName
      });
```

i console log the bDate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5opaP.png

Interestingly the console log shows "1981-03-03" which is the exact format that the error says is required. Also note that this conflicts with the error which says "3/2/1981".

I'll also include the datepicker template for good measure:

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Your birthdate"
        [matDatepicker]="birthdayPicker"
        required
        type="date"
        formControlName="birthday"
        name="birthday"
      >
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthdayPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #birthdayPicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I'm at a loss.  Any help appreciated.